# How to create only a starting tag of an HTML element using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a fixed wp sub-menu list that looks something like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display:flex">
   <li class="open1col"><a>Treatment Trials</a></li>
   <li class=""><a>Alzheimer’s</a></li>
   <li class="close1col open2col"><a href="">Asthma</a></li>
   <li class=""><a>COVID-19 Treatment</a></li>
   <li class="close2col"><a>COPD</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to wrap the first 3 and the last 2 elements into 2 `<div class="sub-menu-col">` elements so that they make two different columns side-by-sidy.

This content is not editable by the way, i can only add classes to li tags.

I have tried jQuery like this:

```
var open1col='<div class="sub-menu-col">';
var close1col='</div><div class="sub-menu-col">';
var close2col='</div>'; 

    $( ".sub-menu li:first-child" ).before(open1col);
        
        $( ".sub-menu li:nth-child(3)" ).before(close1col);
            
        $( "sub-menu li:last-child" ).after(close2col); 
    });
```

but it immediately closed the div after the openning and the 3 `<li>` items fell outside.

How can I add only the opening and the closing tags as html strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how DOM works. You can't insert opening and closing tags separately.

For wrapping elements you can use the jQuery `.wrapAll` method which wraps all the selected elements with a wrapper element.

```
let wrapper = '<div class="sub-menu-col"></div>'
$('.sub-menu li').slice(0, 3).wrapAll(wrapper).end().slice(3).wrapAll(wrapper);
```

Note that the result you are looking for produces invalid HTML. `ul` element should only have `li`, `script` or `template` children.

Comment: The slice() did the trick, thanks! The only problem is that later on i will have to add more items and then I'll have to manually change the slice numbers. It would have been better to tie the end of the wrap to a li item with a certain class. But this is something I can work with for now!

Comment: You are welcome. You are using jQuery. It has numerous methods for DOM manipulation. I suggest reading it's documentations.

Answer (score 1):

While jQuery takes strings as **input**, it operates on a DOM.

There are no start tags or end tags, only elements, text nodes, and other nodes.

So, you can't do that.

---

Work with the DOM instead of trying to fight it.

If you want to create a div and then move some elements inside it, do *that*.

```
const col = jQuery('<div class="sub-menu-col" />');
col.append($( ".sub-menu li:first-child"));
```

etc.

Comment: But I can't add .sub-menu li items one-by-one. Wp makes the list, I can only inject code around it.

Comment: So don't do it one by one. Write a selector that matches all the ones you want to match. Use a loop if need be.

Comment: As I said this content is not editable, it's hardcoded into the WP template that i cannot edit in any way. These list items are database entries and the template uses the Walker_Nav_Menu function to get them from the database. The only thing I can do is to add classes to the li items.